# Java JSoup scrape of an img src from a website returns a weird url

Tags: java, image, web-scraping, jsoup, src

When I try scraping:
https://www.game.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/AjaxCatalogSearchView?searchTermScope=&searchType=&filterTerm=&catGroupId=&maxPrice=&contentOnly=&filterTermOperator=&RASchemaType=&attributeName1=Genre&sType=SimpleSearch&filterType=&resultCatEntryType=2&catalogId=10201&pageView=image&sortBy=MOST_POPULAR_DESC&minPrice=&categoryType=&attributeValue1=4294952868&storeId=10151&langId=44&catgrpSchemaType=&storeOnly=&searchTerm=rpg&searchTermOperator=&pageNumber=1&inStockOnly=true&pageSize=96

for an img I get this as a return:

/wcsstore/SafeStorefrontAssetStore/locale/en_GB/Style1/img/email/spacer.gif

I tried using .attr("abs:src") as well as .attr("src") but both return wrong urls.

```
Elements prods = doc.select(".product");
Elements img = prods.get(i).select(".productHeader a img");
String imageUrl = img.attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is your selector:

Elements img = prods.get(i).select("***.productHeader>a>img***");

That should solve your problem!

NEW ENTRY:
You need to check for "data-src" which has the url for the image without the protocol in front
String imageUrl = img.attr("data-src");

=> e.g. "//img.game.co.uk/ml2/7/3/1/5/731542_ps4_b.png"

Comment: Still the same return as before :(

Comment: ok had to programm java after such a long time :)

what you are looking for ist the "data-src" attribute... the only thing which is missing is the protocol in front:

String imageUrl = img.attr("data-src");

Comment: did you have a chance to try "data-src" ?